# Rails polymorphic join has_many, through returns impossible SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have 3 models set up as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :interests, as: :interesting, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :games, through: :interests, source: :interesting, source_type: 'Game'
  has_many :people, through: :interests, source: :interesting, source_type: 'Person'

end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :interesting, polymorphic: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :interesting_id, presence: true
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, through: :interests
   has_many :interests, as: :interesting
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, through: :interests
  has_many :interests, as: :interesting

end
```

When I try to call `user.games` the SQL run on the database is

```
SELECT "games".* FROM "games" 
INNER JOIN "interests" 
ON "game"."id" = "interests"."interesting_id" 
WHERE "interests"."interesting_id" = $1 AND
    "interests"."interesting_type" = $2 AND
    "interests"."interesting_type" = $3  
[["interesting_id", 3], 
["interesting_type", "User"], 
["interesting_type", "Game"]]
```

so obviously nothing is returned. The query should work, as long as `["interesting_type", "User"]` isn't included.

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to set up the `User` class as well as the `Game` and `Person` class?

I'm using Rails v4.2.6

Comment: You could solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to summarize, the following appears to work in this use case:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :interests, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :games, through: :interests, 
           source: :interesting, source_type: 'Game'
  has_many :people, through: :interests, 
           source: :interesting, source_type: 'Person'

end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :interesting, polymorphic: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true 
  validates :interesting_id, presence: true 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please trying this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :interests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :games, as: :interesting, through: :interests, source_type: 'Game'
  has_many :people, as: :interesting, through: :interests, source_type: 'Person'

end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :interesting, polymorphic: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true # I don't know the reason to use that if you use as polymorphic 
  validates :interesting_id, presence: true 
end
```

The table_name `interests` it should have only the attributes `:id:, :interesting_id, :interesting_type`

Comment: I'm testing but I think it what seems to be working is 
in class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :interests, dependent: :destroy
has_many :games, through: :interests, source: :interesting, source_type: 'Game'
end

Comment: Additionally, the Interest belong_to user and Game has_many :users, as: :interesting, through: :interests

Comment: Yes, The solution I posted appears to work. Thanks for the help!